# Hadoop run time error

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

I have school project to work with hadoop and that will be hosted in amazon EMR.

At first, I'm trying to understand with simple wordcount program and it is running fine at eclipse IDE.

But if I tried to run from command line I'm getting below error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
at counter.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method).

Do you have any suggestion for this error and any resource to understand hadoop and EMR?

Thanks,
myat

Answer (score 0):

Don't run your Job from the IDE or with the java command. Instead use the hadoop script in the bin/ directory of the hadoop installation.

Example: if your Job's starting point is in the mrjob.MyJob class and you have a jar (job.jar) containing your Job class, you should run it like this:

```
path/to/bin/hadoop jar job.jar mrjob.MyJob inputFolder outputFolder
```